# Remove items from array with auto generated onclick

Tags: android

I create a vertical list of textviews with an arraylist and attach on onclicklistener to each one. In the onclick I set code to remove that item. When I click in sequence from the last generated to the first this works fine. But if I remove the first one and then the last one it gives me a null pointer exception. I know this is happening because it is attempting to remove an index that is no longer present, or at least that is what I think is happening. But I cannot figure out how to solve that.

```
private void generateViews(){
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView[] textView = new TextView[questionArray.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < questionArray.size(); i++){
        final int Index = i;
        textView[Index] = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView[Index].setText(questionArray.get(i));
        textView[Index].setId(Index);
        textView[Index].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView[Index].setPadding(15,15,15,15);
        textView[Index].setLayoutParams(params);

        textView[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (textView[Index].getId() == (v).getId()) {
                    questionArray.remove(Index);
                    answerArray.remove(Index);
                    saveVariables();
                    updateViews();
                    ((ViewGroup) textView[Index].getParent()).removeView(textView[Index]);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Question and Answer removed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        mainLayout.addView(textView[Index]);
    }
```

EDIT:

I figured out a small fix but it has it's problems. Instead of removing the items from the arrays with the index I can remove them by searching for the text within the textview.

The problem with this solve is that if my array contains 2 items that are identical then it may remove the wrong index.

```
questionText = textView[Index].getText().toString();
answerText = textView[Index].getText().toString();
if(questionArray.contains(questionText) && questionArray.size() > 0){
    questionArray.remove(questionText);
    answerArray.remove(answerText);                
}
```

Solved:

I solved it by first searching for the index of the question text and removing that index from both arrays. The arrays are user generated and I plan on preventing the user from entering the same question twice.

```
questionText = textView[Index].getText().toString();
int questionIndex = questionArray.indexOf(questionText);
questionArray.remove(questionIndex);
answerArray.remove(questionIndex);
```

Also, I did it this way because I am still an amateur and was not aware of the Recyclerview. I plan on educating myself on that function and hopefully implementing it.

Comment: You want an ArrayAdapter. Not whatever you've done here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should consider using [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea about why you want do this? if you just want remove textview in a list , why don't you use listview or recyclerview instead ?